# How would I add a temporary ban in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Right now, I have the functionality to ban a user but it's always permanent until I manually unban them. And I definitely wouldn't want to go through the hassle of tracking all users banned and so fourth. When a user is banned their account status is set to "Banned" and when they are unbanned their account status is set to their previous account type.

```
accountType: {
  type: String,
  enum: ["Basic", "PRO", "Support", "Administrator", "Banned"],
  default: "Basic"
}
```

So when the user joins they either sign up for the Pro or Basic. Let's say they signed up for Basic & breached some rules that led me to ban them

```
user.accountType = "Banned";
```

That's all I do to ban them and I would love to have it so all bans are only 3 days. If anyone has any solution to this please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `cron job` scheduled once per day for example and check for all the users who has status `banned` if `date` of their banned status passed `3days` then change their status to previous account type.